# Can't read text file in VS code (Python)

Tags: python, file, text, txt

I have this Python code in VS Code:

```
s = open("name.txt")
print("Your name is", s)
```

I have the text file "name.txt" in the same folder as the program I'm running. This text file just contain the text "Johnny".

When running the file, I first got the error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'name.txt'
```

But after some Googling, I turned on the setting "Execute In File Dir":

[image: Setting for opening file]

But now, I instead get this nonsene output:

```
Your name is <_io.TextIOWrapper name='name.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

But it should have been:

```
Your name is Johnny
```

Where does it go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the file, at the moment your output to the `s` variable is an object. To read the file out to a string all you need to include is either:

`s = open("name.txt", "r").read()`
or
`s = open("name.txt", "r").readlines()`

(The `"r"` refers to that you're only reading the file, which is usually implicit but it's good to include it for readability)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked now. Can you please explain what the "r" part of the code means? I think I understand the rest.

Comment: I added an end note about the "r", in your code it's not really necessary because it's the default setting for `open()` but it's good because other people can then see that you're intending only to read the file rather than write to it.